# Sharepoint one column lookup based on other column

Tags: sharepoint

In Sharepoint list can we configure as follows.

1) A lookup Column to select a country.
2) A lookup Column to select a state . This coulmns dorpdown should display only the states belongs to the selected country.

I already have two lists (one stores name of all countries and other the name of states and the corresponding country) These lists are used to configure the above two lookup fields.

Currently the dropdown for country coulnm displays all the 196 Country names and the state dropdown lists all the 3800+ state names.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a `cascading drop down` which SharePoint doesn't offer out of the box.

I would suggest reviewing the options available and picking one.  There are other options but there are several on codeplex.com that might meet your needs ([https://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint+cascading+drop+down+site:codeplex.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint%20cascading%20drop%20down%20site%3acodeplex.com))

If those don't meet your needs and you don't want to buy a commercial offering then you'll have to build your own.  If you have some experience creating custom fields this shouldn't be to difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably exactly what you are looking for
[SP Services Cascade Dropdowns](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation)